# How to type in different languages in JTextArea java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am working on java application where I have a JTextArea in which I want the user to input in Punjabi language.

At the backend, how does Java store that language and also could someone please make a small program illustrating that?

Comment: Input encode by 'UTF-8'

Comment: hmm,,how could i do that @Suzon..??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532056/devanagari-i18n-in-java ah check kro paaji

Comment: Please Take a Look @Gurjit [UTF-8 support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815479/utf-8-support-issue-to-java-swing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setFont to JTextArea. You must install a Font in your system

```
JTextArea t=new JTextArea();
Font f=new Font("Shivaji02", Font.PLAINs, 10);
t.setFont(f);
```

[image]

Comment: No I don't think thats enough at the backend i would like the input strings unicode to be stores..!! Only chaning font wouldnot do that..!!