# Reading properties file via Resourcebundle encoding issue

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm using a resourcebundle to read a properties file based on locale. (Lang_en_US.properties, ..)

The resourcebundle is read as iso-8859-1 (standard?).

```
ResourceBundle rb= ResourceBundle.getBundle("Lang", locale);
```

The resourcebundle is then used throughout the Spring/JSF web-application to generate the front-end text.

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['message.example']}" />
```

But I believe this is irrelevant, as debugging shows that the text is already gibberish right after rb getMessage is called.

```
// returns gibberish:
log.trace(rb.getMessage("l_SampleText"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct in assuming the resourcebundle is read in as iso-8859-1.
[Javadoc of Properties class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle))

Are you sure your properties file is saved under the iso-8859-1 format?
I believe Notepad++ provides the functionality to at least check the encoding, if not convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using UTF-8 characters that might not be encoded properly in ISO-8859-1, you have 2 options

1. Use [nativetoascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) tool to escape the characters in the bundle so that all the chars are read properly
2. Use Spring's [MessageSources's](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2009/04/02/utf-8-encoding-and-message-sources/) bundle support which supports files in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Thanks for these tips, useful! But wouldn't the UTF-8 characters already be messed up by importing them using iso-8859-1 in the resource bundle?