# Java .properties file gibberish when trying to get value in Hebrew

Tags: java, encoding

I'm trying to read Hebrew values from a .properties file and I get gibberish. I've tried a couple of ways, including changing the file's encoding (Cp1255, ISO-8859-8, UTF-8), adding a -file.encoding to the arguments and nothing helped.

This issue was raised during our migration to Weblogic from IAS (OC4J container), I noticed the javascript messages (which are read from a .properties file) appear as `???? ???`, which does not happen on the OC4J. However, this only applies to data read from .properties files, everything else is shown fine.

I've been googling for a couple of days now and I haven't been able to come up with a solution.

EDIT:
What I tried at home

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test");
System.out.println(rb.getString("test"));
```

This is what test.properties looks like:

```
test שלום
```

Output is: `ùìåí`

Comment: We need to see the pieces of what's broken.  Where's the code that reads the files?  What's the .properties file look like?

Comment: it's nothing too special:
the properties file would look like this:
someKey שלום

And I retrieve the value using ResourceBundle.getString("someKey")
(This is what I used on my computer at home and this also generates gibberish)

Comment: That information should be placed in your question or no one will be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have an instance of ResourceBundle and you can get the ISO-8859-1 encoded String with:

```
String strISO = rb.getString("test");
```

You can then convert this to UTF-8 and print it by using:

```
System.out.println(new String(strISO.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Nice trick! Good to have that in the back pocket if you can't modify the bundle itself.

Answer (score 4):

Files for ResourceBundle should be in ISO 8859-1 encoding or in \uXXXX format, just as for Properties. See more at [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)