# How to copy file using UTF-8 encoding before .WAR generation for a Grails application

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, war

I am facing a problem on copying some messages.properties before the war generation, in my Grails application, I am doing it by putting the following code in my 'BuildConfig.groovy' file like [THIS](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/deployment.html) documentation shows :

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(file: "grails-app/conf/custom-web.xml",
         tofile: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/web.xml")
}
```

In this snippet the web.xml is been copied but in mine application I am copying a .propertie file used in some Jasper reports, my code is like bellow:

```
copy(TODIR: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/classes/grails-app/i18n") {
        fileset(dir: "grails-app/i18n")
    }
```

When i open the resulted files it is everything OK (no character problems) but when i generate the report the special character like '^', '`', 'ç', etc.  I have character encode problems. I tried to set UTF-8 in my tomcat server but it does not works too. When I copy the files manually, when the app is already deployed to tomcat, and replace it with the copied by code above IT WORKS. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `.properties` files cannot be encoded in UTF-8:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

This is a strange, well-known legacy limitation of Java. See this question for the workaround:

[How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)