# UTF-8 encoding issues with Spring resourcebundle for special characters

Tags: spring, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am using Spring ResourceBundle to retrieve message bundle from my .properties file. It constains special european characters like so:

```
Ü, ß. ä, ö, ü
```

MessageSouce bean is as below (I am making sure UTF-8 encoding is followed)

```
    <bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/META-INF/i18/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

When I try to retrieve the message in my Java code I am getting Junk characters.

If I use below code, it helps to recognize few characters, but rest are still showing as ??

```
 return new String (bundleString.getBytes(), "UTF-8")
```

Then I used below to encode my properties file, but still no effect

```
native2ascii -encoding utf8 resources.utf8 resources.properties
```

I also tried to manually open my properties file in Notepad++ and set UTF-8 encode, but no effect.
I see a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053710/read-resourcebundle-as-utf-8-getstring-method-seems-to-change-encoding-to-iso), having exact same problem as mine. But the solution uses PropertiesBundle, whereas I have to use Spring based solution only. However even the accepted answer in that link is not working for me, and giving junk characters.

Please suggest any possible solution.

Comment: Please post some examples from the file, both before and after `native2ascii`. Please also provide a partial hexdump of the file.

Comment: Karol, I solved the problem by opening and saving the .properties file in TextPad as "UTF-8" encoding and "Unix" platform. I had taken that same approach, however in Notepad++ without the positive outcome earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue and *@sunny_dev*'s answer worked for me. 
I don't understand why there is not answer for this question yet so I'm updating the question.

*@sunny_dev* answer:

> Karol, I solved the problem by opening and saving the .properties file
>   in TextPad as "UTF-8" encoding and "Unix" platform. I had taken that
>   same approach, however in Notepad++ without the positive outcome
>   earlier. – sunny_dev

Thanks again to *@sunny_dev*

Comment: For those who have Notepad++ , the option of "Convert to UTF-8 Without BOM" or "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" under "Encoding" fixed it for me