# Read Japanese Characters from a properties file using Resource Bundle

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, resourcebundle, properties-file

I am working on developing a project and when I attempt to read in a Japanese character string from a properties file using ResourceBundle in Java, all I get are a bunch of question marks (??????????) displayed in my application.

I know that I need to encode the string somehow, but I've tried several different ways with no luck.  I've also tried to encode the properties file in a text editor but this doesn't seem to work how I'd like either.  My code for retrieving the string is below.  I know you can do this with stream readers and other methods but I would like to try to stay with the current code structure using ResourceBundle if possible.  If anyone has any questions or needs clarification please feel free to let me know.

```
private final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("propertiesFile");

titleText = bundle.getString("title.text");
```

Just to give you an idea, title.text=会議参加者事前登録用ページ  in my property file.

Any suggestions are appreciated.  This has turned into a real pain.

Thanks again,

-Dave F.

Comment: First of all you need to encode the `.properties` file as UTF-8 and then store the characters using its UTF-8 encode representation...I tried that before with Spanish characters and it worked like that, so it should be similar with Japanese characters

Answer (score 1):

ResourceBundle can only read ISO 8859-1 file. See this thread. [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

I had the same problem here, and I've converted my ResourceBundle to a Properties object like in the answer of this thread: [read resourcebundle as UTF-8. getString() Method seems to change encoding to ISO-8859](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053710/read-resourcebundle-as-utf-8-getstring-method-seems-to-change-encoding-to-iso)

Like this:

```
InputStream utf8in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/utf8.properties");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(utf8in, "UTF-8");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(reader);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  This seems like a viable way of proceeding.  If I may ask, once I get a handle to my properties file and encode the file using the above method, how would I get a handle to the **title.text** property within my properties file and assign its value to a string that I can then make use of?

Comment: Just do props.getProperty("title.text"). Also, you can put this code in a class to not repeat it each time you want a localized string.

Comment: Since JDK9 Java expects UTF-8 for .properties. See PropertyResourceBundle javadoc for more info.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I was actually still able to make use of the ResourceBundle method.

In my properties file that ResourceBundle pulls from, I listed the following in unicode:

```
title.text=\u4f1a\u8b70\u53c2\u52a0\u8005\u4e8b\u524d\u767b\u9332\u7528\u30da\u30fc\u30b8
```

When pulled in by ResourceBundle, it translates as:

```
会議参加者事前登録用ページ
```

I'm sure this probably isn't the best practice, but it works without having to change how the entire project pulls in its resource properties, so I just thought I would share with you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your app you can try this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar YourApp.jar
```

this basically sets the default charset

Comment: I have saw this method as well, but unfortunately the project gets build as a .war file using ant

Comment: Even if all your file are encoded UTF-8, you will have the same problem.