# Java Properties File with accented characters

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, properties-file

I'm trying to load a proprieties from a text file, but the accented characters (saül) comes in a different encoding other than UTF-8 how to avoid it?

My property file have a property with an accented character (*saül*). How ever when I remote debug I find that **properties.load(bufferedReader);** takes that as *saÃ¼l* so when I write to another file it gets written as *saÃ¼l*, I have UTF-8 encoding everywhere else in the application. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong while reading the properties from the file.

```
try {
    final String propertyFilePath = System.getProperty(JVM_ARGUMENT_NAME);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(propertyFilePath)) {
        setLocalOverride(true);
        resource = getApplicationContext().getResource(propertyFilePath);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(propertyFilePath), "UTF8"));
        properties.load(bufferedReader);
        externalFilePasswordConfigurer.afterPasswordPropertiesSet(properties);
        LOGGER.info("ExternalFilePropertyConfigurer UTF-8 Reader");
    }
    setProperties(properties);
    logProperties(properties);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("ExternalFilePropertyConfigurer setter failed to set properties: ", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that (ResourceBundle vs Properties).

Comment: That said, I'm not sure I understand the question. If the properties file is using a non-UTF-8 encoding, then use a different parameter to InputStreamReader?

Comment: Agreed with @bkail. The character encoding parameter to InputStreamReader should be changed.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the comments, my property file have a property with an accented character (saül). How ever when I remote debug I find that **properties.load(bufferedReader);** takes that as saÃ¼l so when I write to another file it gets written as saÃ¼l, I have UTF-8 encoding everywhere else in the application. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong while reading the properties from the file.

Comment: Are you sure the properties file is actually written in UTF-8 format? If you use xxd (or write your own program to dump the raw file bytes), does the file contain 0xc3 0xbc for the ü?

Comment: I have no control over that file. it seems like it is not UTF-8

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but as far as I know any .properties file must be in ISO-8859-1 charset or there'll be troubles.

When accented characters are required inside a properties file, each character must be replaced with its unicode version. In this particular case "saül" must be changed to `"sa\u00FCl"`, where `\u00FC` is `"ü"`.

Another solution is change the file type from .properties to .xml

[See java documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> The load(Reader) / store(Writer, String) methods load and store
>   properties from and to a character based stream in a simple
>   line-oriented format specified below. The load(InputStream) /
>   store(OutputStream, String) methods work the same way as the
>   load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output
>   stream is encoded in **ISO 8859-1 character encoding**. Characters that
>   cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using
>   Unicode escapes as defined in section 3.3 of The Java™ Language
>   Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape
>   sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files
>   to and from other character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but I got the same issue and didn't want to change the accented characters to its unicode encoded version.

So I added the following plugin to my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <executions>
            <execution>
                    <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                            <srcDir>src/main/resources</srcDir>
                            <targetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetDir>
                            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                            <includes>
                                    <include>message.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                    </configuration>
            </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

you can read more about the plugin here
https://github.com/mojohaus/native2ascii-maven-plugin