# ResourceBundle (Java)

Tags: java, encoding, resourcebundle

I need the character like 'шел' in my .properties file.

It seems like ISO 8859-1 (Which seems to be the default .properties encoding) doesnt like these, and displays them as ?.

I want to support this characters, what to do?

**EDIT: I made it work now, but everytime I use this it converts my file from UTF-8 to ANSI (So the file gets replaced with the same file but then in ANSI), really weird. Code: http://pastebin.com/r0h3CKXF**

Any idea why this happens??

Comment: Use a properties editor. They can also present several languages (files) side-by-side. They may present full Unicode text, but store it in IISO-8859-1,u-escaped as `\uXXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode can be encoded with `\uxxxx` in property files.

Comment: Isn't there another workaround? I dont like having my files unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle JDK contains a tool named `native2ascii` that converts property files to Latin-1. Write your .property file in UTF-8, and then call

```
/path/to/jdk/bin/native2ascii -encoding utf8 input.properties output.properties
```

You can also read UTF-8 encoded .property files. See [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/) for a detailed description.

Comment: And then? ResourceBundle reads it still as ISO 8859-1, which doesnt support these characters

Comment: This tool will convert all non-latin-1 chars into escape sequences (`\uxxxx`)

Comment: Is it possible to automate this with Java? (So it checks for convertable text / convert it every startup)

Comment: I don't think it is. However, you could write a tool that scans directories for .property files and converts them if you like.

Comment: @BammerbomTheKing Instead of just calling the one-argument `ResourceBundle.getBundle` method, call the getBundle method that takes both a name and a [ResourceBundle.Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) argument.  Pass in your subclass of ResourceBundle.Control which overrides the `newBundle` method to create a PropertyResourceBundle from a Reader which uses an explicit charset, rather than an InputStream.

Comment: I am currently using new PropertyResourceBundle(FileInputStream). How would I use ResourceBundle.Control now?