# Convert UTF-8 string to literals

Tags: java, utf-8

I want to store a UTF-8 string `"Русслэнд"` in a Java properties file as UTF-8 literals like this `"\u0420\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043b\u044d\u043d\u0434"`

How can I convert this? Since Java properties files are ISO-8859-1 by default.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Comment: Thanks, is there a way without ResourceBundle?

Comment: You can also do Properties.load(reader) and pass a UTF8 compatible reader.

Comment: Take care to use the correct terminology. Those are not "[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) literals", but UTF-16 character literals. You're putting people on the wrong track by mentioning UTF-8.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as an "UTF-8 string". Strings are just sequences of characters. When you convert them to bytes, then you use a character encoding. But a string doesn't have a character encoding by itself. (Java internally uses UTF-16 to store characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a command line tool to do conversions

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 x-utf8.txt x.properties
native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 x.properties x2-utf8.txt
```

Also there are comfortable properties editors that let you enter in unescaped Unicode, and can display several languages side-by-side. For instance in the standard NetBeans IDE.

Also possible is to keep the UTF-8 file as source and have **maven** or **ant** copy and convert the file to the build directory.

And then there is the option to load Properties with an encoding; a bit too specific.

Comment: Thanks I want to do it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Try StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)