# Hashing String (SHA-256) in an ActionListener class

Tags: java, exception, event-listener, checked-exceptions

I want to use the following code in an `ActionListener` class.

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));

BigInteger HashValue = new BigInteger(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash).toLowerCase(), 16);
String HashValueString = HashValue.toString();
```

But the `"SHA-256"` and `"UTF-8"` can't be imported in any way. When I do this in a console program, I can solve this with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
```

But I can't in an `ActionListener` class. How can I solve this?

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know in advance that `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")` and `key.getBytes("UTF-8")` will succeed, so the best solution is to wrap a try-catch around the impossible checked exceptions:

```
try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = digest.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    BigInteger HashValue = new BigInteger(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash).toLowerCase(), 16);
    String HashValueString = HashValue.toString();
    // ... The rest of your code goes here ....

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

Now with this code, you do not declare a `throws` on your `ActionListener` method, as required by the contract.