# VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString falls with UTF-8 and spanish letters

Tags: java, character-encoding, velocity

After `mergeTemplateIntoString`, the spanish simbols like Ñ and ñ falls.

```
public String loadData (VelocityEngine velocityEngine, Map mParam) {

        String result;

        try {

            result = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "informesHtml/template.vm",
                mParam);

            return result;

        } catch (VelocityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The `.vm` template use `UTF-8` and the DB `WE8ISO8859P15`. I've tried to change a `velocityEngine` format, but  without success. The spring framework version is 4.3.9.

Comment: Did you check this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897865/how-do-i-get-spanish-characters-to-display-properly-using-a-velocity-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set `text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1` in the `.html` file and now everything works fine.