# Property from properties file being read in the wrong encoding

Tags: java, encoding, javafx, controlsfx

I have a properties file with some properties in Portuguese language, using some accented characters. These properties are read from a 3rd party library (Controls FX Dialogs). But somehow the accented characters are being read in the wrong encoding (tested only on MS Windows).

This is what i have in my properties file:

```
dlg.yes.button = Sim
dlg.no.button = Não
```

And this is how it looks on the running app:
[image]

All my project files (including java sources and properties files) are encoding in UTF-8. I can only test it on windows, so i think it has something related to windows default encoding (Cp1252). I also tried to run the app using UTF8 encoding with the option -Dfile.encoding=UTF8, but the problem still persists

Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property files are always treated as ISO-8859-1 files.  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-):

> The input stream is in a simple line-oriented format as specified in [load(Reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) and is assumed to use the ISO 8859-1 character encoding; that is each byte is one Latin1 character.

You will need to either save your file as ISO Latin-1, or write all non-ASCII characters using `\u` escapes.