# How to make a tamil property file in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts, properties-file, tamil

I tried to create a tamil language property file in my java ee project.

I entered Language code as '**ta**' , And I didn't fill Country code or variant.
My Sinhala and English translations are showing perfectly in web browser. 
But my tamil translation shows only some squares.

I tried to open those tamil words in Ms Word 2010 document too. But they show some random characters. Although I installed some Tamil fonts still this one is not working alteast in my word document.

Another problem is other English and Sinhala property files are blue. But Tamil one is green. Is that because I didn't complete the creation process of property file?

Please help me with this. I'm being desperate here.

Thank you

**I added '\u' before the translation.** And it returns to English Language(Default). Can any one explain why?

Comment: It may be that the errors are with the `.properties` file. `.properties` files are in ISO-8859-1 (always), so you have to enter the Tamil translation strings in encoded form. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle for an explanation for that.

Comment: @DaDaDom Thanks I'll look into it.