# Read ValidationMessages encoded in utf-8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator, spring-4

How do you change the resource bundle of validation messages? The default one is reading my ValidationMessages.properties as ISO-8859-1 (I guess) but it is UTF-8. I tried this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean( name = "messageSource" )
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource validationMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("ValidationMessages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(validationMessageSource());
        return validatorFactoryBean;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }
```

Whatever I put here this is not used by Hibernate to get messages.
Any tips?
I'm using Hibernate 5 and Spring 4.

Comment: Are you sure it's not using "UTF-8"? Can you call `messageSource.getDefaultEncoding()` at runtime and double check?

Answer (score 3):

`.properties` file are per specification read in `ISO-8859-1` encoding (aka `Latin-1`. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties and [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)). So you need to specify the unicode characters instead of saving the file as `UTF-8`.

To use the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` with Hibernate you need to wire it up to JPA else it will use the default one.

Add the following property to your JPA properties of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

```
<entry key="java.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator" />
```

Adding that will make it use the Spring Configured instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource validationMessageResource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("ValidationMessages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .messageInterpolator(
                        new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
                                new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(validationMessageResource())
                        )
                )
                .buildValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator()
                ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to make UTF-8 to work is to use java class instead of properties file.

Just add ValidationsMessages.java, ValidationMessages_fi.java etc. to your src folder root.

```
public class ValidationMessages extends ListResourceBundle {

@Override
protected Object[][] getContents() {
    return new Object[][] { 
        { "user.name", "Name is not valid" } 
    };
}
```

}