# Grails 3.2 Resource Bundle does not display text with correct encoding

Tags: grails, internationalization, grails-3.2

Since Grails 3.2.8 (and above) the resource bundle within my application does not work as expected. German umlauts (or general UTF-8 chars that are not part from ASCII) are display with ��. E.g. the German word *über* is displayed as *��ber*.

First I suspected the `processResources` Gradle tasks that performs `native2ascii`. But my UTF-8 resource bundle files are properly copied to `build/resources/main/*.properties` and converted to `US-ASCII`.

The source file is clearly encoding using UTF-8.

`file -I grails-app/i18n/messages_de.properties
grails-app/i18n/messages_de.properties: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

after running `./gradlew clean processResources` all the resource bundle files are successfully processed by `native2ascii` and encoded using `US-ASCII`.

```
file -I build/resources/main/messages_de.properties
build/resources/main/messages_de.properties: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

All non ASCII chars are escaped.

`event.free.space={0,number} von {1,number} verf\u00fcgbar`

While debugging my application running as a standalone WAR using

```
java -jar -server -Dserver.address=127.0.0.1 -Dserver.port=50000 \
    -Dgrails.env=prodMySQL -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
    -Xmx768M -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 \ 
    build/libs/my.war
```

I noticed that the `org.grails.spring.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource` loads my `messages_de.properties` file using UTF-8 encoding since it logs the following message.

```
s.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource : Loading properties [messages_de.properties] with encoding 'UTF-8'
```

After loading the properties file into to the a `java.util.Properties` class, I see all non ASCII characters as e.g. �.

Any clue whats going wrong here?

Comment: I have the same problem, opened an issue with grails-core on Github: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10832

Comment: I noticed that this issue only applies when I build my war using `gradlew clean build` while having my Grails project open in IntelliJ. If I close IntelliJ before building with Gradle everything works as expected. Strange behaviour....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and for me the solution was in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268213/6899501

in `resources.groovy` set the `defaultEncoding` to `'UTF-8'` for the `messageSource` bean.