# Saving special characters in properties file

Tags: java

I have property with string that contains some special characters. After I save it to properties file I have:

```
BB\u0161BB=0
```

I don't like character represented with `\u0161` . Why it can't save like character I see it on the screen and type from keyboard?

UPD
What is the easiest way to read ini-file architecture file that contains special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can!

Encode your file in unicode (UTF-8, for instance) using another application (Notepad++ is nice, for instance) and read your properties file like this:

```
File file = ... ;
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
     Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
  properties.load(reader);
}
// use properties
```

There you go, properties file in any charset that you can read and use.

Answer (score 3):

That's how Properties files are defined to behave. Any other system is likely to use UTF-8 which might not be readable either.

As your character is outside the range of an ISO-8859-1 encoding, it has to use unicode instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. From javadoc:

> ...the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character
>   encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this
>   encoding can be written using Unicode escapes as defined in section
>   3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence.

Please refer to this [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Answer (score 1):

Properties files are ISO-8859-1 encoded, so characters outside of that set need to be `\uXXXX` escaped.