# Localization using Spring Validator displays HTML entities escaped instead of unescaped

Tags: spring, localization, html-entities

I have my validator which implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator`. When I use `errors.rejectValue("myField", "myErrorcode")` for some form if in my error code defined in `language_it_IT.properties` contains HTML entities like `&agrave;`, then it will display as `&agrave;` on html page not as `à` as I want. How I can achieve that?

Comment: _... it will display as "à" on html page not as "à" as I want_ I can't see the difference.

Comment: Sorry it displays "& agrave" without space of course but I don't know how to insert it here without space

Comment: As to the concrete problem, special characters in properties files need to be escaped as unicode codepoints like so `\u00E0`, not as HTML entities. HTML entities is for HTML files only, not for properties files. Decent IDEs like Eclipse and IntelliJ do that automatically in their properties file editor. If you're using such an IDE, just put the `à` right away in the properties file instead of its HTML entity counterpart. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Comment: Thak you, I am using unicode codepoint and it is works.