# JavaFX multilanguage .properties file encoding

Tags: java, javafx, encoding, multilingual

I have a problem with displaying characters with diacritic like á, í, č, etc. 
I've set .properties file to UTF-8 with ISO 8599-1 but when I run following code I dont have wanted result.

Main class:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles.language_sk", new Locale("sk", "SK")));
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/loginFrame.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 563, 580);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
```

Login Frame controller class:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle
                .getBundle("bundles.language_sk", new Locale("sk", "SK"));
        setLoginBtnText(bundle);
    }

    public void setLoginBtnText(ResourceBundle bundle){
            loginBtn.setText(bundle.getString("loginButton"));
    }
```

language_sk.properties file:

```
#LOGIN FRAME
.
.
loginButton=Prihlásiť
.
.
```

Result:

[image]

So as you can see, I've tried to set text of Login Button using .properties file but characters are messed up.

Although when I use this code in `setLoginBtnText` method:

```
 public void setLoginBtnText(ResourceBundle bundle){
        String val = bundle.getString("loginButton");
        try {
            loginBtn.setText(new String(val.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

then text on button is perfectly fine. How can I set some global encoding settings for my whole project so I dont have to specify encoding at each one component in each class? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things:

- "set .properties file to UTF-8 with ISO 8599-1" doesn't mean anything. It is UTF-8 OR ISO 8859-1, not both
- it seems that your property file is in UTF-8 encoding on the disk (you can check it with hex editor - you will see two bytes for each special character)
- locale you are passing to ResourceBundle initializer is not helping with language/charset decoding, it is just used to select proper bundle; if you are passing _sk in name yourself, then it is probably not needed
- ResourceBundle understands only ISO 8859-1 by default from what I understand and I don't think that all SK characters are there

What you need is UTF-8 encoded resource bundle (which you seem to have by accident) and load it as such. Please look here for description how to do it
[How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using special characters from FontAwesome, I use the scaped version of the UTF-8 character to print it without a problem.

```
icon.disengage=\uf35d
```

You must add "\u" before the 4 digits character code.