# Deltaspike i18n encoding error

Tags: java, internationalization, cdi, deltaspike

I'm using Deltaspike Core for retrieving and showing messages in different languages. I'm using the default MessageContext implementation but with a custom MessageResolver. It worked fine until I tried to use a properties' file codified as UTF-8.

THe UTF-8 file is locale_source.properties with a message:

> messageKey=Localización no disponible.

And my code looks like this:

```
public class MessageBuilder {

    @Inject
    private MessageContext messageContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        messageContext.messageSource(LOCALE_SOURCE);
    }

    @Override
    public Message create(String key) {
        Message m = messageContext
                .clone()
                .localeResolver(new MyOwnLocaleResolver())
                .message()
                .template("{" + key + "}");
    ...

System.out.println(messageBuilder.create(messageKey).toString());
```

It retrieves the message but with a codification error:

> LocalizaciÃ³n no disponible.

As you see it changes the ó for **Ã³**. Is there something to specified the codification of the properties file? What else can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this that answer my question: [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

So the solution is basically keep the properties files in Latin1 and use unicode codes \uXXXX to represent those symbols that are not covered by that encoding.