# Which properties file encoding to use for javafxports project?

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, gluon-mobile, javafxports

My project has properties files for language dependent texts which are encoded (per default derived from content type) in ISO-8859-1.
They are read using `ResourceBundle`.
When I run the application on Android I see non-printable characters (e.g for german umlauts äöü).

When I convert the files to UTF-8 then the presentation on Android is fine but now I see non-printable characters when running the application on the (Windows) desktop.

Is there a way/encoding to keep the same files for Windows and Android ?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- convert all properties files that contain non-printables to UTF-8
  (e.g. using notepad++)
- for these set file property in IDE (e.g. Eclipse->file->Properties->Resource->text file encoding) also to UTF-8
- implement UTF8Control as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle) and use this for all ResourceBundles where its baseName may load an
  UTF-8 encoded file (Luckily I had only a few places to change in my
  java code).
- If a `ResourceBundle` is passed to `FXMLLoader` it should also be UTF-8 enabled.