# Eclipse French and Russian characters problem in properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, character-encoding

Eclipse shows french characters as Question marks in *.properties files

example:
`V�rifiez votre abonnement`

and Russian characters as:

`\u041F\u043E\u0434\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u043F\u043E\u043`

can you help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660195/597657

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Not Working

Comment: Which Java version? In Java 8 and lower the encoding of a `.properties` file is ISO-8859-1, in Java 9 and higher UTF-8. The `\u...` encoding works in all versions, so the first example might be an invalid `.properties` file.