# Sending UTF-8 message to Xpages

Tags: java, jsf, utf-8, xpages, facescontext

I have an XPages application for Swedish users.

When I am sending a message to the facescontext via

```
msg = propStrings.getProperty("gen_CustDateDecided") ;
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
facesContext.addMessage("msgBox", new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(msg));
```

The text for the that is broadcasted resides on a properties file, with UTF-8 encoding.

When loading the properties file I make sure it is read in UTF-format:

```
private Properties getPropertiesFromFile(String fileName) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream is = FacesContextEx.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            prop.load(r);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, null, fileName, Level.WARNING, null);
        }
        return prop;
    }
```

The text that appears on the messages control on the Xpage:
Senaste beslutsdatum i kundkommittÃ©n

The text in the properties file:
gen_CustDateDecided=Senaste beslutsdatum i kundkommittén

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property files are not encoded as UTF-8. They are ISO 8859-1. You need to encode them accordingly. Easiest is to just use a few lines in a standalone Java class to save properties. Takes care of encoding.

More details here:
[How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: good to know, I was in the assumption they would be saved like that since I can set in the editor which format files should be saved