# How to set UTF-8 for resource bundle properties in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, properties, resourcebundle

IDEA somehow doesn't truly enable UTF-8 encoding for properties files in the project. Therefore, when I try to use my multilocale properties with cyrrylic characters, it shows a kind of mess. Settings show as follows: "UTF-8 disabled for properties".
Is there a way, how to force set UTF-8 for .properties?

Similar topic on intellij blog recomends to set ISO 8859-1 encoding for properties in this case. But shouldn't it work with UTF-8?

Image is attached.[image]

Comment: For legacy reasons, Java properties files are always ISO-8859-1 files.  You have the option to create your own InputStreamReader with a different charset, and pass that to [load(Reader)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)).

Comment: see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Comment: @VGR: As of Java 9, they are UTF-8 by default. The from Marcel Stucki explains it in more details.

Comment: @D.Kovács Properties files are used for more things than just ResourceBundles.  It is true that ResourceBundles treat resource bundle properties files as UTF-8 by default.  However, for all other general uses, [Properties files are treated as ISO 8859-1 files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)).