# SpringBoot - Message.properties not displaying french special characters

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding, utf-8

In springboot i have messages_fr.properties.
I have a value that is publicités, images clés but it displays as publicit�s, images cl�s.

I have tried setting UTF-8, not working.
Below is my code.

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

This is how i fetch the key :-

```
messageSource.getMessage(myKey, null, Locale.French)
```

Please advise if i have to add anything.

Comment: What Java version are you running ? Java 9 and higher, this should just work. Java 8 requires escaping special characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660195/1076463

Comment: I am using Java 11

Comment: Is the file itself encoded in UTF-8? I would use external editor to verify this. E.g. on Windows you can use Notepad++ -> encode in UTF-8. On Linux Sublime should do the trick.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - Done that.. I had pasted the contents in Notepad++ to check in Encoding menu...It showed UTF-8

Comment: These artifacts usually happen between UTF-8 with BOM and without BOM. Rather than pasting the contents in Notepad ++ use Notepad++ File-> open and navigate to your file. Then you can convert to UTF-8 with BOM and UTF-8 without BOM. Do both conversions and see if any of it will change what you see in Notepad++ and then what you see after running your code.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Thank you so much bro ! Converting the file to UTF-8 with Notepad worked perfectly for me