# Encoding problem, does not translate into Russian

Tags: java, spring

Configured Spring for internalization and localization, but encountered a problem in encoding. English characters are displayed normally, but instead of Russian text, question marks ???????.
And messages_ru.properties the following problem arises from the file " Unsupported characters for the charset 'ISO-8859-1'"

label.home=Главная Страница

label.about=О Нас

label.name=Наименование

label.price=Цена

button.add=Добавить

Configuration Code:

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    source.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
    return source;
}

@Bean
public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
    resolver.setCookieName("language");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600*24*365);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("lng");
    return interceptor;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
    registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrCH3.jpg)

Comment: Where are you seeing the questions marks? Is it a webpage, JSON response, console, what is it?

Comment: The answer may depend on the version of Java that you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle

Answer (score 1):

Russian characters are not part of charset `ISO-8859-1` and you have to use `UTF-8`.

The `messages.properties` file must be UTF-8 encoded because Spring doesn't convert it automatically even if you define `setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");`.

Open your `messages.properties` file with an editor and make sure it has `UTF-8` encoding.