# Not show correct russian text from message bundle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, message-bundle

```
java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

Here my messageBundle_ru_RU.properties (**UTF-8**):

In IntellIJ IDEA 2022:

[image]

And in java code read like this:

```
private static ResourceBundle resMessagesBundle;

  private static String getTranslateString(String key) {
        String result = resMessagesBundle.getString(key); 
        return result;
    }
```

but result is not correct:

```
Ð’ÐµÑ€ÑÐ¸Ñ
```

Comment: what is java version? https://openjdk.org/jeps/226

Comment: You got the word 'Версия' in incorrect encoding. It seems you are converting the text from UTF8 to Windiws-1252 encoding. Check the encoding of your output channel.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I was update my post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov This help: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle/