# How to convert from Java ASCII properties to UTF8 (Java 9) properties

Tags: java, utf-8, properties

I have an ASCII encoded Java properties file with unicode escapes (\u0123) in them that I need to convert to the new Java 9 UTF-8 format. So control character escapes (\r, \n, ...) need to stay but e.g. \u00E4 should become ä (UTF-8 encoded).

The motivation to convert them to UTF-8 is that it simplifies the workflow with translators.

I've tried multiple options with iconv and uconv (from ICU) but was unable to get a good result. Asking chat GPT also didn't yield a fully working solution.

This is *not* about troubles with UTF-8 Java properties files in editors or how to get UTF-8 properties files to work in Java pre-9.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Doesn't Java 9 read correctly the Unicode escape sequences?

Comment: If you've got an older (Java 8) jdk around: `native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 input-file.properties output-file.properties`

Comment: @aled This question here is exactly a step required to move away from ASCII + escapes in properties files towards UTF-8, as UTF-8 is natively supported in Java 9+. It's a good related link though as you still need to convince your editor to read it as UTF-8 (which your link explains).

Comment: @g00se Would you be able to provide this as an answer? It worked perfectly for me. I used OpenJDK8 u181. The native2ascii was apparently removed from version 9 on though.

Comment: I could do, but I'm a little nervous about its no longer being supported.. e.g it might not support codepoints > 0xFFFF

Answer (score 1):

```
cat messages.properties | awk -v RS='\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}' '{ORS=""; print $0; printf "%c",strtonum("0x"substr(RT,3)) } END {print ""}'
```

`RS='\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}'` sets the record separator to a regex which matches unicode escapes

The `{...} END {print ""}` block is then run for every record (string without unicode escape plus one unicode escape).

`ORS=""` makes sure the record separator is not replaced by anything when printing $0

`print $0` prints the string before the record separator

`printf "%c",strtonum("0x"substr(RT,3))` First extracts the hex value from \u0123 (the substr part), then prepends '0x' so strtonum interprets it as hex, converts this to a number (strtonum) and prints it as a character code (printf "%c").

`END {print ""}` is a no-op but needed to close the previous {} block

Comment: Here's a Powershell version for those on Windows: `(Get-Content -Path "messages.properties" -Raw) -replace '\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})', { [char][Convert]::ToInt32($matches[1], 16) } | Out-File -FilePath "updated_messages.properties" -Encoding UTF8`. Though it would still be better to use OP's solution via Git Bash or MSYS2.